# Using result of an API call to POST/PUT it into another API

Tags: php, api, rest, design-patterns, integration

Im quite new using api calls.
I wonder if it is a proper programming design to use the result of a GET call to PUT or POST it into an other API.

Example: Server A has product datas. A script will do a GET call and save the product datas into arrays. After that a script will do a POST or PUT call to import these datas into Server B. The API structure of Server A and B is completly different. The script would be php or python. Server A has a PHP-API. Server B has a REST-API.

Is this a good way? If not what would be the recommended way of handling this scenario?

Comment: can't they communicate directly with each other?

Comment: I dont think thats possible or i dont know how. The systems on the servers are not the same and there is no connector or something implemented on Server A to communicate with systems like Server B it is.